# need radius of convergence of $e^{-x^{2}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am having difficulty finding the radius of convergence of

> $e^{-x^{2}}$

this is for introductory analysis course.  Have looked at even and odd subsequences of powerseries, but so far unable to put the pieces together.  Any help appreciated.

Started with:
$e^{-x^{2}} = \Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{2k}}{k!}= \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n$

s.t. $S_n = 0$ 
when n odd and 
$S_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\frac{n}{2}!}$ when n even.

Then $S_{2n+1} = (0,0,0,0,...)$, converging to $0$, and $S_{2n} = \frac{1}{n!}$, and with ratio test we get

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{1}{n!}}\right| = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = 0$

Comment: are you sure the $e^{-x^{2}} = -\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}= -\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n$ because $e^{-x^{2}}$ is always positive while $-\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}= -\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n$ is always negative

Comment: corrected, I think

Comment: still negative notice the difference between $-x^{2k}$ and $(-x)^{2k}$

Comment: thanks.  any input on logic/methodology errors, or simply the notational?

Comment: for ratio should have an $x$ somewhere in there and if it ends up converging to zero for any $x$ then radius of convergence is infinity i.e. interval of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: like this?
$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n!}x^n}\right| = |x|lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = |x|0$
and if so, is it enough to show both even and odd subsequences converging to 0?

Comment: if original sequence converges to zero you have any subsequence converges to zero. Im a little confused why you want to prove that to prove radius of convergence though

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that 
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x)^n}{n!}$$
we then have
$$e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}$$
Thus by ratio test we see
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{x^2}{n+1}\right|=0$$
Thus the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and interval of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$